# Get Error in Create button with event and message box using perl language

Tags: perl, button

I am new to perl programming. I am trying to build **create a button with event and message box** using Perl language. This button call event and camming message box. I use the **Padre Perl IDE** for doing this task.
After it ran, came error.

**Error:**

> error variable is not of type Wx::Point at 05_button_with_event_and_message_box.pl line 37.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

**my Perl code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package main;
use 5.008;
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

my $app = Demo::App->new;
$app->MainLoop;
package Demo::App;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Wx::App';
our $frame;
sub OnInit {
    $frame = Demo::App::Frame->new;
    $frame->Show(1);
}
package Demo::App::Frame;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Wx qw(:everything);
use base 'Wx::Frame';

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(
        undef, -1,
        wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, );
    my $button = Wx::Button->new( $self, -1, "What is this smell?" );
    Wx::Event::EVT_BUTTON(
        $self, $button,
        sub {
            my ( $self, $event ) = @_;
            print "printing to STDOUT\n";
            print STDERR "printing to STDERR\n";
            Wx::MessageBox( "This is the smell of an Onion", "Title", wxOK | wxCENTRE, $self );
    }
    );
    $self->SetSize( $button->GetSizeWH );
    Wx::Event::EVT_CLOSE(
        $self,
        sub {
            my ( $self, $event ) = @_;
            $event->Skip;
        }
    );
    return $self;
}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks any audience.

Comment: Please indent your code & Include your error, This just contains the code!

Comment: error                                                                                                                 variable is not of type Wx::Point at 05_button_with_event_and_message_box.pl line 37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to provide the window title argument in the call to
`Wx::Frame->new()`:

Try this:

```
my $self = $class->SUPER::new(
    undef, -1, "My title",
    wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, );
```

**Note**:

I have not use `wxWidgets` before. I was able to install the `wxPerl`
now on Ubuntu 16.10 using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install gtk2.0
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libwx-scintilla-perl
cpanm Wx::App
```